# MySql complex query | How to DELETE from SELECT and HOW to CREATE SUB-LIST FROM ARRAY

Tags: mysql, sql

Im working with this table:
[The Table I start with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiNkV.png)
and I have the next sql :

```
SELECT customer_id, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(incident_id order by create_time asc) as ids,
   count(incident_id) as total_count 
FROM incidents 
GROUP BY customer_id
```

this sql generates the following table
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF8py.png)

I would like to perform a DELETE query on the generated table.
I tried to do this :

```
DELETE FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(incident_id order by create_time asc) as ids,
        count(incident_id) as total_count 
    FROM incidents 
    GROUP BY customer_id)
WHERE total_count > 3
```

BUT I received an error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeKxd.png)

What am I doing wrong?

And second question -->
Once I will know how to delete from this table, I would like to extend the delete term ( which was "where total_count > 3" ) and add to it another term that will delete all the rows where ids are above 3 so I will be left with only 3 ids.
In postgress I will do it by adding the next term :
incident_id = ANY(ids[3:total_count])
Meaning I want to create sub-list from the group.
How do I do it in MySql?

To sun it up, I would like to execute the following sql :

```
DELETE FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(incident_id order by create_time asc) as ids,
           count(incident_id) as total_count 
    FROM incidents 
    GROUP BY customer_id)
WHERE total_count > 3 
     AND incident_id = ANY(ids[3:total_count])
```

Comment: We don’t want images, we want text.

Comment: Pls do not ask multiple questions in a single post because it is a lot more difficult to answer, accept answer, and search such questions. You cannot delete from a derived table. A derived table (subquery) can be used to limit the records you are deleting from an actual table. Your delete statement must target the incidents table.

Answer (score -1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d14a1da/2

```
DELETE i.* FROM incidents i
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id, 
        count(incident_id) as total_count 
    FROM incidents 
    GROUP BY customer_id
    HAVING total_count >3) f
ON i.customer_id = f.customer_id
```

Comment: @TalLevi if this answer worked for you; Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)